# Installing SSL for sub domain which pointing to another server

Tags: ssl, dns, ssl-certificate

I have domain www.xyz.com with dedicated IP,SSL for www.xyz.com is already installed and working fine.
now through plesk panel i am able to create 10 sub domains.

I have created one sub domain named subdomain.xyz.com which is pointing to totaly different server.

I want to add SSL certificate for subdomain.xyz.com.

where i have to add SSL certificate, on the the server that sub domain is pointing or i can add SSL for subdomain.xyz.com from xyz.com plesk panel.

the subdomain is pointing to solaris server

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the SSL certificate on the actual server that is responding to your HTTPS requests (meaning, the one the subdomain points to). However, keep in mind that if you have a regular SSL certificate, then the certificate would have to be issued to the specific subdomain. For example, a regular SSL certificate for example.com does not validate against sub.example.com.

As an alternative, you can purchase a wildcard SSL certificate for your domain that will cover the new subdomain and any others you add later. More info on that here: https://www.digicert.com/wildcard-ssl-certificates.htm